# Iterate and sum two different array of objects and return new array- JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is that possible to sum two different objects from array object and to return single array of object?

```
let source= [{
  "supplimentKing": [{
    "pwdrName": "zzzzz",
    "pwdrPrice": "2"
  }],
  "protinsAddonOffer": [{
    "pwdrName": "oooo",
    "pwdrPrice": "3"
  }]
}];
```

**result:**

```
[{
  "pwdrName": "zzzzz + oooo",
  "pwdrPrice": "5"
}]
```

After trying to understand similar [SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479107/sum-all-data-in-array-of-objects-into-new-array-of-objects) , [SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449295/how-to-sum-the-values-of-a-javascript-object), [SO 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57505330/javascript-how-to-filter-an-object-array-and-sum-result) i could not understand how to get expected result.

could some one pls help me how to sum the properties in clean way?

Thanks

Comment: You want to merge all the objects in the array to a single value/object ?

Comment: This just needs a `for` loop and `parseInt()` - So what have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: @Andreas , first i tried to filter price n name then reduce it  by summing them both

Comment: Yes... @Nithish

Comment: Why `.filter()`? o.O Just iterate over the elements

Comment: because there lot of properties inside the response but i want to do summation on selected offer combination

Comment: @Andreas i dont want to complicate by using nested  or two independent for loops since it has two different object from same array.

Comment: why does expected output have key supplimentking if it pulls data from other places too.  do any/all of those arrays of objects contain additional elements.

Comment: @James ""supplimentking  is just for understanding. and Yest has many. i just give necessary properties for summation  i edited my thread. Thanks

Comment: why is each object in the source array, an array of object (one...)?  And prices as Numbers - this makes more sense: 
`source= [
  {
    "pwdrName": "zzzzz",
    "pwdrPrice": 2
  },
  {
    "pwdrName": "oooo",
    "pwdrPrice": 3
  }
];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reduce to add values

```js
let source= [{
  "supplimentKing": [{
    "pwdrName": "zzzzz",
    "pwdrPrice": "2"
  }],
  "protinsAddonOffer": [{
    "pwdrName": "oooo",
    "pwdrPrice": "3"
  }],
  "proAddonOffer": [{
    "pwdrName": "iiiii",
    "pwdrPrice": "3"
  }]
}];

p=[]
  source.forEach((o)=>{
    p.push(...Object.values(o))
  })
  v=p.flat()
total= v.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
  acc= [{"pwdrName":curr.pwdrName+"+"+acc.pwdrName,"pwdrPrice":Number(curr.pwdrPrice)+Number(acc.pwdrPrice)}]
  return acc[0]

})
console.log([total])
```